# code in elseif block partially running when it shouldn't

Tags: php, if-statement

Ok, I have a registration form for my site.

When there are errors up pops a box with the errors. The box is made up of an html div, an h2 header, and php echoing my errors.

If I hit submit it shows the errors like it should, but the header and div show up no matter what.

I dont understand why.

Here is the code block that echoes the errors.

```
} else if (!empty($errors)){
    echo '<div class="msg_module">';
    echo '<h2>Registration Errors:</h2>';
    echo $General->outputErrors($errors);
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Thanks all!

Edit: I should mention that $errors is an array.

EDIT: My internet is back, here is the outputErrors function:

```
public function outputErrors($errors = ''){

        if(is_array($errors)){
            // handle for passed array
            foreach ($errors as $error){
                if(is_array($error)){
                    general::outputErrors($error);
                } else{
                general::$errStr.= ($error != '')?'<li>'.$error.'</li>':'';
                }
            }
        } else if($errors != ''){
        // handle for passed string
        general::$errStr = $errors;
        }
    return '<ul id="error_list">'.general::$errStr.'</ul>';
 }//outputErrors
```

Comment: `$errors` is obviously not empty. - just echo $errors to see what is there.

Comment: All it says is 'array'.

Comment: So you might need to use the PHP version of "array length" instead of "empty" (not doing PHP at the moment, so I'm out of touch with the details)

Comment: What I expect to happen is for the div to not show up unless there is an error in the form. If my internet didnt just go out I could post you the validation code.

Answer (score 0):

Use `var_dump($errors);` and you will probably see that the variable is not empty.

From your comment, I assume that the variable is of **type** array

Read the [PHP Manual for the empty function](http://www.php.net/empty) and you will see that it returns true for **empty arrays** (arrays not containing any element)

Now remember that if the variable is of **type** String, then most strings are considered non-empty.

Comment: It has an empty array in it. Not sure why though its filled by if statements that if an error is found: $error[]='error message';

Comment: Does `$General->outputErrors` modify the array in any way?

Comment: My computers internet went down so I cant show you, but it takes the array and puts the values into <li></li> tags and then into an unordered list and returns it.